# Undefined symbol: _GADUnifiedNativeIconAsset while migrating GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook with GoogleMobileAds iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-mobile-ads, facebook-ads

I would like to migrate Facebook mediation with Google Mobile Ads.

**Pod:**

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
```

Getting the below error after migrating to the latest version 11.2.0.

```
Undefined symbol: _GADUnifiedNativeIconAsset
```

It is working fine if I downgrade pod to `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '10.14.0'`

Kindly let me know if anyone has an idea to fix the above issue with the latest pod file.